# function inside a function - global and nonlocal scope

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying out the following code with global, and nonlocal scope. following snippet working wihtout any issues.

```
def countdown(start):
  n = start
  def display():
    print('--> %d' % n)
  def decrement():
    nonlocal n ##using python3
    n -= 1
  while n > 0:
    display()
    decrement()
countdown(10)
```

countdown(10)

but why can't i use the global n ? instead of nonlocal n. that gives me

```
 UnboundLocalError: local variable 'n' referenced before assignment
```

this is the snippet

```
 def countdown(start):
   global n   ##defined it global
   n = start
   def display():
     print('--> %d' % n)
   def decrement():
     ##no nonlocal varibale here
     n -= 1
   while n > 0:
     display()
     decrement()
```

countdown(10)

Comment: Your python2 version of `countdown` doesn't allow for more than one countdown to be active. It's probably a better idea to replace `n` with `display.n`. That way you don't need a global variable, and the dict of the `display` inner function serves as a namespace for the mutable local `n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The global declaration doesn't automatically apply to nested functions. You need another declaration:

```
def decrement():
    global n
    n -= 1
```

so `n` in `decrement` also refers to the global variable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to mark a variable as global in every  function where you use it (or rather, every one where you assign to it).  You marked `n` as global in `countdown`, but `decrement` still thinks it is local.  If you want `decrement` to also use the global `n`, you need to put another `global n` inside `decrement`.